C# library - Create NuGet package with Sdk type Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web
I'm quite familiar with NuGet package generation, but this is the first time I'm trying to generate a package with a Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web sdk type instead of the typical Microsoft.NET.Sdk.
I know this is probably uncommon, but I need this type of sdk to reference AspNetCore specific types (SignalR hubs) which are not available in the classic sdk format.
I always set these properties in my .csproj file to have the nuget package (.nupkg file) generated:

PackageId
Authors
Company
Version
Target frameworks
GeneratePackageOnBuild (true)
GenerateDocumentationFile (true)
DebugSymbols (true)
DebugType (full)

Usually, this is enough to have my package properly created - but not with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web sdk format. I played a bit to create test scenarios and isolated the issue, I'm pretty sure this depends on the sdk format and not something else.
Expected behavior: .nupkg file generated in output directory (bin/Debug).
Actual behavior: Project builds but no .nupkg file is generated.
Has anyone already faced this issue?

What exactly went wrong? What is the result instead of the expected?

@Fildor you're right, I updated my question.

"but I need this type of sdk to reference AspNetCore specific types" Can't you add  a reference to the assembly of the types you need?

Try changing back to the Microsoft.NET.Sdk and adding the FrameworkReference element:
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>

See the Use ASP.NET Core APIs in a class library doc.

Thank you, this solved the problem. I also found another workaround while reading the output log from build process: add true to my .csproj also worked.
